# Setting the params:id issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am editing the index.html.erb page in the sources view

```
<% @sources.each_slice(20) do |s| %>
  <div class="span3">
  <% s.each do |i| %>
    <div><%= link_to(truncate(i.name, :length => 30) , sources_path(i.id), :class => 'action show') %></div>
  <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The sources.controller is..

```
 def index
   @sources = Source.search(:search=>params[:search])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @sources }
    end
  end
```

Q: When the params[:search] is valid. Why does the i.name info get presented and the i.id doesn't...How can I get the i.id?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not related to the **id**, it's most likely related to the fact that you're using **sources_path** instead of using **source_path**.

Comment: Even if I change it to <div><%= link_to(truncate(i.name, :length => 30) , {:controller => "Sources", :action=> 'show' , :id => i.id }, :class => 'action show') %></div> I still will not pull the i.id

Comment: What's the HTML it is generating?